# minix; after i try to use mined / shutdown i get the error

Tags: c, minix

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCCp1.png)

I just installed Minix and tried to use mined a shutdown function. I got the error 12. I tried to google it, but I couldn't find anything. How can I change shutdown's source code?

p.s. I also tried to cd /shutdown but it didn't worked. and I couldn't vi /shutdown and I googled "Minix segmentation fault" and I found nothing.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

`shutdown` is a binary file with the executable code. `mined` was probably not able to deal with such a large file. The file you want to edit is named `shutdown.c`.